# get some section of text from an html then apply to another html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html file that contain the contents of whole website, each section of text is in a p tag with id. Now in another html, for example address.html I want to get the address text from that content html. I tried the following:

```
.controller('addresscontroller', function($scope,$http){
  var xx = document.getElementById("addressSection").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("address").innerHTML = xx;
});
})
;
```

Some explanations: In the content html, there is a section that look like this

```
<p id="addressSection">the address</p>
```

In the address.html, I want to apply the address to:

```
<p id="address"></p>
```

Now the problem is seems like it doesn't read from content html. Any help on this?

By the way, I also tried to use iframe and embed, iframe always has a frame and embed can only apply the whole content html so I guess these are not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In address.html, put:

```
$('#address').load('content.html #addressSection');
```

This will apply the contents of the element with id `addressSection` in the loaded page (content.html in this example) to the matched element with id `address` in the current page.

See http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I put it in the controller it doesn't work, should I put it in the html? like <script>$('#address').load('content.html #addressSection');</script>